# AWS Data Pipeline Cannot Connect with RDS Mysql (connection time out)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-data-pipeline, amazon-rds

I am stuck on making a AWS Data Pipeline which takes data from RDS Mysql to s3.
I ahve tried Template but failed alot. Then I made this self configured pipeline but still no success. Can anyone point out the problem by seeing the architect?

**Here are the RDS MySQL Details -> NOTE <- that username in picture is different because I am using a separate user and the username in picture is administrator**
[image]

**This is the Data Pile Line Architect**

[image]

**Below are the settings of first block i.e Configuration**
[image]

**Below are the settings of RDS MySQL DataBase**
[image]

**Below are settings of EC2 Machine**

[image]

**Below are the Settings of SQL Data node - which i guess gets data from RDS**
[image]

**Below are the Settings of Copy Activity**
[image]

**Below are the settings of S3 Data Node - which i guess puts data on S3**
[image]

**Here is the ERROR LOG**
[image]

I read that it could be an error due to VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) permissions but I am not sure how to add these settings as the server is a Production Server and I am afraid to perform this test. Can any one provide a solid solution please?

Comment: In what VPC and subnet is your EC2 instance? your EC2 instance is not able to connect to the DB did you try connecting to the RDS from your EC2 instance?

Comment: Can you provide a dump of the DBserverSG-prod security group?

Comment: @error2007s how to check EC2 instance's VPC and subnet? I opened EC2 on console and there are more than 500 instances running on the Production server

Comment: @RodrigoM Can you tell me how to get that dump, I will check with the security team if I could share that

Comment: Are you able to locate  this machine "Below are settings of EC2 Machine"

Comment: In this Data Pipeline Architect, I think an EC2 instance is created on the fly. What do you think.

Comment: To dump the security group, try aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id sg-60b0f105 --output table

Comment: @error2007s I have searched in all those instances by the name "DefaultResource2" as this was the name of that EC2 instance. Also I looked at all t1.micro type instances but could not find that. While the Data Pipeline  was running (Trying to connect)

Comment: @RodrigoM Is it ok to share these types of Dumps? I am confused

Comment: Yes if you change any ip number to 192.168.0.X for example

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, your ec2 instance is not able to contact the Database endpoint.   Please use the link to configure the security groups correctly http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html

To test this,  spin up a ec2 instance in the subnet and telnet to the database endpoint to ensure the connection is fine.  You can then resume the activation of your pipeline.

Commands

1. sudo yum install telnet
2. telnet hostname port

Comment: We Connect with RDS MySQL using a VPN. I guess that VPN's IP is added into VPC Security Group. But how will I add my EC2 in that security Group?

Comment: You need to create a Ec2 Security group say ESG and add it to the 'allowed' list in the VPC security group.  Then any ec2 instance launched with ESG can then connect to the DB inside the VPC.  In this case, you need to the specify the ESG in the 'securityGroup' slot of the Ec2Resource in datapipeline.

Comment: How do you 'ADD IT TO ALLOWED'?
VPC security groups and EC2 Security groups are two different things made for same purpose. Explain your comment please